# Laravel sum quantity and group by product_id and return table data

Tags: laravel

## Table Data:

```
id || product_id || quantity || sold_price || image (Relationship)
1  ||      1     ||    10    ||     10     || 1.png
2  ||      2     ||    5     ||     20     || 2.png
3  ||      1     ||    15    ||     15     || 1.png
```

## Expected return data

Sum of repeated `product_id` which is `25` and average sold price of `sold_price` which is `10+15/2 = 2`

To get average we get `sum/counter` as you already know.

***EXPECTED RESULT***

```
id || product_id || quantity || sold_price || image (Relationship)
1  ||      1     ||    25    ||     12.5   || 1.png
2  ||      2     ||    5     ||     20     || 2.png
```

## What I have tried

```
$products = SoldProducts::whereIn('export_invoice_id', $export_invoice_ids)
            ->groupBy(DB::raw('product_id'))
            ->select([
                'sold_price',
                DB::raw('sum(quantity) total_quantity'),
            ])
            -> get();
```

But this return only `total_quantity` and `product_id` without `id, average_sold_price, image`.

## Problem

Problem is that `image` is from a relationship.

I have tried to use `with('image')` but select doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood the question properly the following code should rectify your issue.

```
$products = SoldProducts::whereIn('export_invoice_id', $export_invoice_ids)
    ->groupBy('product_id')
    ->join('images', 'product.image_id', '=', 'images.id')
    ->select([
        'products.id',
        'products.product_id',
        DB::raw('sum(products.quantity) AS quantity'),
        DB::raw('(sum(products.sold_price) / count(*)) AS sold_price'),
        'images.image'
    ])
    ->get();
```

If you use select, you need to select every column you require in the select for Eloquent to retrieve it, otherwise, it won't pull the column for you.

You need two DB::raw in your select - one for quantity and one for the sold price as per your specification; Quantity is a simple sum. It sums up all the items per product id. The sold price is summed to start with then divided by the number of that product_id.

**Edit:** I've updated the code example - but since you haven't specified how the image is joined to the table I've taken an educated guess. You may need to make it ->leftJoin if you don't always have an image assigned.

Comment: Sorry I have edited the question.. image are from relationship